# Saber qué elemento se repite más y cuál menos en un arreglo

Tags: java, array

Necesito ayuda para completar un programa. Sólo me falta saber qué arreglo se repite más y cuál menos.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class practica {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int canal1,canal2,canal3,canal4,canal5;
        int i,n;
        int arre[]=new int[20];
        Scanner lector=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("cuantas personas se les preguntaron");
        n=lector.nextInt();
        int canal=5;
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        System.out.println("[1]=canal 5");
        System.out.println("[2]=canal 7");
        System.out.println("[3]=canal 13");
        System.out.println("[4]=canal 4 ");
        System.out.println("[5]=canal 2");
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            System.out.println("que canal eligio ");
            arre[i]=lector.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tienes que explicar mejor que necesitas, que quieres y que has probado ya. Si no es imposible ayudarte.

Comment: Podrias hacer un array de repeticiones, donde el valor 0 del array sea canal 5, el valor 1 canal 7 etc...  Haces un +1 en el valor, y luego una comprobacion, comprueba el primero con el segundo, si es mayor, el primero con el tercero y asi sucesivamente

Answer (score 1):

Creo que entiendo el concepto del programa, y aquí tienes mi versión. Espero que te ayude.
Lo único que falta a este código es evaluar cual es el canal que más frecuencia tenga y el que menos, pero eso lo puedes hacer tu fácilmente con esta base.
No hay ninguna validación, pero sería interesante que las añadieses por tu cuenta para que la respuesta fuese correcta.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Practica {

/* 
    La función de este programa va a ser pedir un número 'n' de 
    interacciones, y en cada interacción
    podemos seleccionar 5 tipos diferentes de canales.
    Tras las 'n' interacciones, analizamos los resultados, mostrando el 
    canal que menos se ha seleccionado
    y el que más.

    Podemos mostrar también el número de veces que se ha seleccionado cada 
    canal como ampliación
*/

// Main
public static void main (String args[]) {

    // Scanner
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Declaramos variables
    // Numero de interacciones
    int n;
    // Declaramos el array donde vamos a almacenar las respuestas
    int [] respuestas;

    // Pedimos el numero de interacciones que se desean:
    System.out.println("Numero de interacciones: ");
    n = sc.nextInt(); // No voy a entrar en validaciones

    // Creamos el array con la capacidad 'n'
    respuestas = new int[n];

    // Creamos un bucle que se repite 'n' veces
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // Imprimimos el menu y guardamos la respuesta en una variable
        int r = menu();

        // Almacenamos esa respuesta en el array 'respuestas'
        respuestas[i] = r;

    }

    // Contadores, para ver el numero de respuestas de cada tipo
    int canalA = 0;
    int canalB = 0;
    int canalC = 0;
    int canalD = 0;
    int canalE = 0;

    // Recorremos el array respuestas, y analizamos los resultados
    for (int i = 0; i < respuestas.length; i++) {
        int r = respuestas[i];

        // Clasificamos las respuestas utilizando los contadores
        switch (r) {
            case 1:
                canalA++;
                break;
            case 2:
                canalB++;
                break;
            case 3:
                canalC++;
                break;
            case 4:
                canalD++;
                break;
            case 5:
                canalE++;
                break;
        }

    }

    // Imprimimos los contadores
    System.out.println("Canal A: " + canalA + " veces");
    System.out.println("Canal B: " + canalB + " veces");
    System.out.println("Canal C: " + canalC + " veces");
    System.out.println("Canal D: " + canalD + " veces");
    System.out.println("Canal E: " + canalE + " veces");

    /* 
       Te he enfocado bastante el programa, ahora tú tienes que mostrar el 
       que más frecuencia tenga
       y el que menos
    */
}

// Método para imprimir el menu que deseamos y guardar la respuesta
public static int menu() {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("------------------------------");
    System.out.println("1. Canal A");
    System.out.println("2. Canal B");
    System.out.println("3. Canal C");
    System.out.println("4. Canal D");
    System.out.println("5. Canal E");
    System.out.println("------------------------------");

    System.out.print("Respuesta: ");

    // Debes validar que la respuesta sea 1 - 5
    int respuesta = sc.nextInt();

    return respuesta;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class practica {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int canal1,canal2,canal3,canal4,canal5;
        int i,n;
        int arre[]=new int[20];
        int repeticion [] = new int[5];
        int iNumeroMayor, iPosicion;

        //Presuponemos que el numero mayor es el primero
        iNumeroMayor = listaNumeros[0];
        iPosicion = 0;


        Scanner lector=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("cuantas personas se les preguntaron");
        n=lector.nextInt();
        int canal=5;
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        System.out.println("[1]=canal 5");
        System.out.println("[2]=canal 7");
        System.out.println("[3]=canal 13");
        System.out.println("[4]=canal 4 ");
        System.out.println("[5]=canal 2");
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            System.out.println("que canal eligio ");
            arre[i]=lector.nextInt();
            repeticiones[i] = repeticiones[i] + 1;
        }
       for (int x=1;x<repeticiones.length;x++){
                if (listaNumeros[x]>iNumeroMayor){
                       iNumeroMayor = listaNumeros[x];
                       iPosicion = x;
                }  

        }
    }
}
```

Algo asi igual te serviria, no entiendo muy bien en si tu codigo, pero algo como esto te podria valer